# Jupyter kernel points to the wrong Python

Tags: python, virtualenv, jupyter, conda

I create a conda environment, activate install ipykernel, add it to jupyter kernelspec. This far, all works fine.

`conda create -n MYENV python` 
`conda activate MYENV` 
`conda install ipykernel` 
`python -m ipykernel install --user --name MYENV` 
`conda deactivate` 
`jupyter kernelspec list`

> `MYENV    /home/kara/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/MYENV`

Then I launch the jupyter notebook on my base environment, and select the added kernel. However, while this kernel still runs, it uses the python from the base environment.
When I type `!which python` in the notebook, it returns "/home/kara/anaconda3/bin/python" while my python in that environment is actually in;

`conda activate MYENV` 
`which python`

> `/home/kara/anaconda3/envs/MYENV/bin/python`

How can I get jupyter to find the correct python? Now, when I install a package in that environment, jupyter cannot find it. I suspect it's because the package install to a different environment.

Comment: Can you select the envs kernel under `kernel->Change Kernel`?

Comment: Yes, I can select them. I see the kernel I create and I select it.

Comment: As a `nb_conda_kernels` user (no manual registration of kernels), I encounter no such problems. I.e., `!which python` resolves to the kernel's Python.